# regex preg_replace breaks when bbcode

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm creating highlights of the searchwords on the results page.

This is what I use now:

```
$resmessage = preg_replace ( '/' . preg_quote ( $searchword, '/' ) . "/iu", '<span  class="searchword" >' . $searchword . '</span>', $resmessage );
```

But when the word is an title name on a attachment is will break the layout.

example text:

```
test ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]
```

The result:

```
test ok test-2.png" title="test-2.png" rel="lightbox[imagelink2]">  test-2.png" style="max-height:800px;" alt="" />
```

So I want exclude none character before searchword.
What is the regex to do that, I have tried many options.

Comment: What do you mean by `none character`? Whitespace?... or what is `$searchword` so I can run the test locally.

Comment: like ] 
searchword = test

Comment: So if white space trails the search term replace it? From example output should be `<span  class="searchword" >test</span>ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]`, is that right?

Comment: Or bold is the best way, so you have:
[b]test[/b]ok n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment], 

There must be a space after the searchword to find the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you. `\s` is a white space (tab, new line, or space), `+` says one or more occurances of a white space character.

```
<?php
$resmessage = "test ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]";
$searchword = 'test';
echo preg_replace ( '/' . preg_quote ( $searchword, '/' ) . "\s+/iu", '<span  class="searchword" >' . $searchword . '</span>', $resmessage);
```

Output:

```
<span  class="searchword" >test</span>ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]
```

You can replace it with whatever you want the second parameter of preg_replace is what you want there. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

So

```
echo preg_replace ( '/' . preg_quote ( $searchword, '/' ) . "\s+/iu", '[b]' . $searchword . '[/b]', $resmessage);
```

would give you

```
[b]test[/b]ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]
```

Comment: Works almost. When the Title is just "test"  then isn't highlighted

Comment: Can you provide a full sample on input with `test` in it? In your above example would it become `testok test-2.png" title="test-2.png" rel="lightbox[imagelink2]">  test-2.png" style="max-height:800px;" alt="" />`? You could change the `+` to a `*` but that's the equivalent of not checking for the whitespace because it no longer would be required.

Comment: <?php
$resmessage = 'test';
$searchword = 'test';
echo preg_replace ( '/' . preg_quote ( $searchword, '/' ) . "\s+/iu", '<span  class="searchword" >' . $searchword . '</span>', $resmessage);

Comment: No, I mean when `$resmessage`, the string you are searching, would have the search term without a space and you'd want to find it. For example what if you had tester, testing, testosterone, testimonials, etc. in your string would you still want to only find `test`? If so all would become `[b]test[/b]`....ending of word, is that what you'd want?

Comment: What I want is to highlight all search terms, except in attachments or url bbcodes. Because the bbcode changed to html, and breaks the image result, and showed the html as in: http://s24.postimg.org/xmgd4jgl1/Untitled.jpg

So I want a regex to search words except [*] is for the searchword

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using regex backtracking control verbs (the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` part).

This will allow you to match any string that is not inside BBcode (either between tags or the tag name itself):

```
$searchword = "test";

$resmessage  = "test attachment ok \n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment] test ";
$resmessage .= "[test]test[/test] ok [attachment=1]my-test-2.png[/attachment] test";

$pattern = '/\[.+?\].*?\[\/.+?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|' . 
    preg_quote($searchword, '/') . 
    "/iu";

$resmessage = preg_replace(
    $pattern, 
    '<span class="searchword">' . $searchword . '</span>', 
    $resmessage
);
```

This will return:

```
<span class="searchword">test</span> attachment ok 
[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment] <span class="searchword">test</span> 
[test]test[/test] ok [attachment=1]my-test-2.png[/attachment] 
<span class="searchword">test</span>
```

Comment: This will break the bbcode. Same as in my first post.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code that breaks?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I didn't mean the broken code, I need the original string before it goes through any processing.

Comment: original string:
test ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]

Comment: It works fine for me: http://ideone.com/fork/a0X5Nv, access it and click run, you'll get: `<span class="searchword">test</span> ok /n[attachment=1]test-2.png[/attachment]`

Comment: its bbcode, and the real html is:
    <a href="/master/media/kunena/attachments/665/test-2.png" title="test-2.png" rel="lightbox[imagelink2]">
 <img src="/master/media/kunena/attachments/665/test-2.png" style="max-height:800px;" alt="" />
</a>

Comment: So it looks to me like you are running the regex after you replaced the BBcodes with HTML code. Can you run the regex before you parse the BBcode?

Comment: Thnx but I will choose the solution from chris. Because I have parse issues when I do it before.